# Do I need to stop a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a separate `Thread` in my project. Every hour a scheduler starts a thread to get files from a server and store them in my database.

My code works as it should. Since the scheduler starts a new `Thread` every hour, I don't know if I need to stop the `Thread` manually or not?

```
 try {
        Runnable task = new MyClass();
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();

 } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception-Thread: " + ex.getMessage());
 }
```

My Class (runnable)

```
  public class MyClass implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                //Do stuff...
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A Thread will always 'stop' when it's done with it's `run()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not have a permanent loop or something similar inside the `Runnable`, then no you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the thread has not chance of doing infinite loop
Such as using while loop. Thread will stop once all the tasks in `Runnable` are done.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to stop the Thread manually. More than that the `stop()` method of thread is `@deprecated` and not safe:

> This method is inherently unsafe.  Stopping a thread with Thread.stop
>   causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked

`Thread` will finish its job when it will escape `run` block. More than that you need do to some effort to keep it running.

You need to start looking into `Executors` framework and not operate `Threads` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Thread life cycle has following states

> New,
>   Runnable,
>   waiting,
>   Timed waiting,
>   Terminated,

the first thing you should not stop your thread directly as it can cause shared variable in an inconsistent state, and if you want to then you have to make a proper flow to terminate the thread.

To take your thread in a terminate state you have to see if it is not in waiting, timed waiting or worse case in the active state depends how you have handled it.

If you are not doing any of this then need not to otherwise please make a proper method to terminate the thread.